# Convenient way to do "wrong way rebase" in git?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I want to pull in newer commits from `master` into `topic`, but not in such a way that `topic` changes are replayed over top of `master`, but rather vice versa. I want the new changes from `master` to be played on top of `topic`, and the result to be installed as the new `topic` head.

I can get exactly the right object if I rebase `master` to `topic`, the only problem being 
that the object is installed as the new head of `master` rather than `topic`.

Is there some nice way to do this without manually shuffling around temporary head pointers?

*Edit:*

Here is how it can be achieved using a temporary branch head, but it's clumsy:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b temp   # temp points to master
git rebase topic       # topic is brought into temp, temp changes played on top
```

Now we have the object we want, and it's pointed at by `temp`.

```
git checkout topic
git reset --hard temp
```

Now `topic` has it; and all that is left is to tidy up by deleting temp:

```
git branch -d temp
```

Another way is to to do away with `temp` and just rebase `master`, and then reset `topic` to `master`. Finally, reset `master` back to what it was by pulling its old head from the reflog, or a cut-and-paste buffer. This gets it down to six steps, still awkward:

```
git checkout master
git rebase topic  # solve conflicts, git rebase --continue, if necessary
git checkout topic
git reset --hard master  # topic and master same now
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD@{13}
```

It is better to rely on some saved commit hash in the last step than to go hunting through the reflog.

#### Why this is useful

Suppose you have some people working on branch, who are collaborating on some development which is isolated from `master`, but stays integrated with it on a regular basis. By doing the rebase this way, we can avoid non-fast-forward changes on the branch (rewriting the branch history). How `master` is treated when it comes time to integrate the branch into it is another story; but there are options, including scenarios that avoid non-fast-forward manipulation of `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have, e.g.:

```
A - B - C - D - E    <-- master
          \
            F - G    <-- topic
```

and you want:

```
A - B - C - D - E             <-- master
          \
            F - G - D' - E'   <-- topic
```

where `D'` and `E'` are copies of `D` and `E`?  (I'm not at all sure this is what you want; it would help a lot if you draw a graph of what-you-have vs what-you-want.)

The simple way to do this is with `git cherry-pick`.  While on `topic`, cherry-pick everything new on master—commits `D` and `E` above, but easily obtained programmatically:

```
git cherry-pick topic..master
```

Comment: No, rather topic ends up being `F - G - D' - E'`.  New changes `D` and `E` on master are rewritten/replayed and grafted onto `topic`.  Of course, I do not want two versions of `F` to appear in `topic`.

Comment: `cherry-pick` looks promising, except it seems to be tedious to deal with when it halts midway due to a commit being hard to apply (compared to `rebase --continue`).

Comment: Oops, yes, I'll fix the answer text.  (Newer git has `cherry-pick --continue` too.)

Comment: I've been able to get the effect I'm looking for with `cherry-pick`. If this is done more than once, it will be tricky; you will have to know which commit to start from. But that is a consequence of doing this wrong-way rebase. Once you start rewriting the trunk changes, you're diverging from that point on.

Comment: Yes, I can see that after a while, knowing which commits to cherry-pick would get crazy.  You can help yourself by leaving a marker (a tag, for instance; any ref-name will serve) pointing to the last cherry-picked ref.  Use `git update-ref` to set an arbitrary ref (not in either `refs/heads/` nor `refs/tags/`) if you want to avoid using tags.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, but have you tried `git merge master --squash` and then `git commit`?  This should move the latest state of `master` into `topic` with an additional squash commit to specify that the merge took place to get it into the state you're looking for.

This might not be exactly the way you want to mod your commit graph, though.

Comment: No merge; I do not want to collapse any changes, except those that happen to naturally disappear in the rebase due to obsolescence.